# Using an ESP8266 and getting compilations errors when trying to convert a bytearray to a string

Tags: c++, esp8266

I'm really new to C++, especially with the ESP8266. I have a simple callback function that is called each time a message is put on an MQTT queue. The following code is supposed to read the bytes, convert into a char* and pass them to the LED to display.

A friend suggested the following 2 lines to convert the bytes into a char.

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void callback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length) {

// copy the bytes into a string var
std::string byteString(payload, length);

// Then if you need to access it as a char*
char* charString = byteString.c_str()

 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print(charString);
 delay(2000); 
 
}
```

However, this seems to fail with

```
basic_string.h:147:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'byte*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::__sv_wrapper'
```

I did try to google the error, and I did see some similar errors suggesting I was maybe using an older verison of C++.

This is my first adventure into the world of C++ and moving beyond basic copying and pasting examples for my ESP device, and I'd be really grateful for any pointers, or explanation as to what I might be missing here.

Thanks so much!

Comment: what is `byte` ? `std::byte` ?

Comment: Here's the right way to learn boutique domains of knowledge, like esp8266 development: Step 1, spend 3-5 years learning C++ core fundamental topics; Step 2, after acquiring average to expert level of core C++ fundamentals, branch out into specialized, boutique areas like esp8266 development. Attempts to skip step 1, and instead use a search engine to fill in the knowledge gaps, will always end in tears. The compilation error is due to some basic, core, C++ fundamental issues (namely that there is no suitable `std::string` constructor). There are also other issues, this is just the 1st one.

Comment: `c_str` returns `const char*`. Isnt this another compiler error?

Comment: Try `std::string byteString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(payload), length);`. Though it's unclear why you want `std::string` in the middle - to add a NUL terminator?

Comment: Thanks Igor.  I'll try the std::string byteString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(payload), length); 

Thanks for your comment, Sam. Just to reassure you, it hasn't ended in tears. This is just a fun project I'm using to learn how things work. I tend to learn best by trying things out.  Sometimes it's cool when things don't work :)  

Thank you for your comment though, as I now know there is no suitable constructor, and potentially that there may be other issues, so I can now look for a new approach in parallel to learning C++ a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I wasn't able to cast the byte array as a string, however as I know the length, I've just created a string of the same size, null terminated it and copied the bytes from the byte array.

I'm sure this is not ideal, but until I learn a little more C++ it's printing ascii chars to my LCD display. The entire purpose of this device is literally to print temps to an LCD display.

Thanks for everyone who helped me on the right track.

```cpp
void callback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length) {

  
 char lcdmsg[sizeof( payload ) + sizeof( ( char )'\0' )] = { '\0' };
 memcpy(lcdmsg, payload, length);

 // Print to the display
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print(lcdmsg);
 delay(2000); 
 
}
```

Comment: `char lcdmsg[sizeof( payload ) + sizeof( ( char )'\0' )] = { '\0' }` -- This is a bug that will result in a buffer overrun if `length` is greater than `sizeof(byte *)`.  The `sizeof(payload)` is the same as `sizeof(byte *)`, which is either going to be 4 or 8, depending on the environment.  Instead of all of this, you could have used `std::vector<char> lcdmsg(length + 1);` and then use the vector's `data()` method to get to the underlying `char` buffer.  *After some trial and error,* -- See SamV's comment in the main section that speaks about learning C++.

Comment: Bottom line is that if you are using `sizeof` in a C++ program, you need to be aware that it is a *compile-time* value, not a runtime value.  It shouldn't be used to compute the length of runtime information.  I see this error so many times with new C++ programmers who use `sizeof` as a universal "length finder", when it is not that.